# Can't enable Product Categories feature in MedusaJS

Tags: medusajs

I'm using MedusaJS 1.19 with PostgreSQL. Not too long ago they released beta feature - [Product Categories](https://docs.medusajs.com/modules/products/categories). I enabled feature flag and run migrations as docs say, but I still do not see the feature in the Admin

Did anybody try to make this work? I'm on Windows 10, what can be the reason for the feature not appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because my project was created before Medusa v1.8 with separate repos for backend and Admin frontend

I was trying to enable the feature in separate Admin repo, and I assume new features are meant to be for the newer version of Admin, which, since v1.8, is a package that is installed inside backend repo

I concluded that it's not possible to enable this feature in older versions of Admin